# Object comparison doesn't work with more than 1 column

Tags: powershell, csv, comparison

My script has to compare 2 columns with different header names in 2 CSV files, and write the differences to a txt file. Here is my code:

```
Write-Host "Script output will have unique items from file 1"
$FirstPath = Read-Host -Prompt "Input file location of first .csv file"
$SecondPath = Read-Host -Prompt "Input file location of second .csv file"

Write-Host "Importing CSV files..."
$FirstFile = Import-Csv $FirstPath
$SecondFile = Import-Csv $SecondPath 

Write-Host "Comparing files..."
$SecondFile | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name Url -Value Url2
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FirstFile -DifferenceObject $SecondFile -Property Url -PassThru |
    Where-Object{$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} |
    Out-File .\result.txt

Write-Host "Done, press any key to continue..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

What I figured out so far:

Everything works fine if there is only 1 column in each file. Alias for 2 different header names works, searching works, write to output file also.

The problem is when I'm trying to search CSV files with more than 1 column. If CSV file with alias has more than 2 columns, it gives this error:

> The member 'Url2' is not present

If the first file - ReferenceObject has more than 2 columns, output is a whole first file.

**Edit:**

2 example CSV files that I'm comparing:

```
Url;Fail 
test1;failvalue1 
test2;failvalue2
```

```
Url2;Fail2
test1;failvalue1
test3;failvalue2
```

Output should be only "test1", since I'm comparing "Url" with "Url2" through an alias property. If I delete the "Fail" and "Fail2" columns, leaving only 1 column in each file, everything works as mentioned before.

Comment: Could you show the code that doesn't work? There are no references to Url2 anywhere in your example

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's this alias at $SecondFile | Add-Member, its -Value

Comment: Well, sounds like there is no Url2 column in the $SecondFile input file then, please post sample input

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Done

Comment: `Import-Csv` -> `Import-Csv -Delimiter ';'`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I god damn knew it was something so simple... Thanks mate, I'm really gratefull :)